# Haskell, print out fmap result

Tags: haskell

I would like to print result of fmap like this

```
 putStrLn <- fmap (replicate 3) [1,2,3,4]
```

But I got putStrLn parse error.
Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Note that you can use `map` with lists :) (but `fmap` is also correct)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct syntax here is:

```
putStrLn $ show $ fmap (replicate 3) [1,2,3,4]
```

or, even shorter:

```
print $ fmap (replicate 3) [1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 5):

Totally not the answer the asker is looking for, but humorously his syntax misunderstanding is still valid Haskell code:

```
do putStrLn <- fmap (replicate 3) [1,2,3,4]
   return putStrLn
```

The above uses the list monad and the value `putStrLn` is just a variable (not the IO action one might expect).  It might make more sense to people if expressed as a list comprehension instead of using the list monad:

```
> [ putStrLn | putStrLn <- map (replicate 3) [1,2,3,4]]
[[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4]]
```